# Why is $\bar{h}$ halfway from the surface instead of being the same height as the resultant force $(2/3) h$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, pressure, fluid-statics

[image]

I'm confused with the formula for hydrostatic force $F = yhA$. The force follows a triangular load where the resultant force is at 2/3 of the height, but $h$ in the formula doesn't follow this height. Why is that?

Comment: Pressure linearly depends on depth and the average pressure is being used.